# How to remove the value in dropdown if the value is already selected in another dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have multiple dropdowns using ng-repeat.In the dropdown, I am populating the value through a $scope array.

For Example

```
$scope.list = ["A","B","c"]
```

Consider in the first drop if I have selected A then the other dropdown should not allow the A to select and If I have selected B in the next dropdown and I would like to change the first dropdown value then it should allow me to select only A and C.

> HTML:

```
<select>
   <option ng-value="val" ng-repeat="val in list">
     {{val}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second list that will be called `cleanList` for example. This will serve you as data source for the second drop down list. See this example

```
$scope.list = ["A","B","c"];
$scope.cleanList = ["A","B","c"];
$scope.onSelect = function(){
     $scope.cleanList=[];
   for(var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++){
     if($scope.list[i]!=$scope.otherVal)$scope.cleanList.push($scope.list[i]);
   }
}
```

And your htmls

```
<select>
   <option ng-value="otherVal" ng-repeat="val in list" ng-change='onSelect()'>
        {{otherVal}}
    </option>
</select>

<select>
   <option ng-value="val" ng-repeat="val in list">
        {{val}}
    </option>
</select>
```